# Как сделать так чтобы нажав на одну кнопку вторая заблокировалась? Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

```html
<label>КНОПКА 1<input type="radio" name="radio" /></label>
<label>КНОПКА 2<input type="radio" name="radio" /></label>
```

Comment: Что значит заблокировалась?

Comment: Не нужно править ответы. Дополняйте собственный вопрос или уточняйте в комментариях ниже.

Comment: @Arthur прекратите несвязанные правки. Задайте новый вопрос

Answer (score 4):

Назначаем обработчик кнопкам, в котором устанавливаем свойство `disabled = true` всем кнопкам, кроме нажатой:

```js
const aBtns = document.querySelectorAll('[name="radio"]');

aBtns.forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
    ev.stopPropagation();
    aBtns.forEach(btn => {
      btn.disabled = btn != this;
    });
  })
});
```

```html
<label>КНОПКА 1<input type="radio" name="radio" /></label>
<label>КНОПКА 2<input type="radio" name="radio" /></label>
<label>КНОПКА 3<input type="radio" name="radio" /></label>
<label>КНОПКА 4<input type="radio" name="radio" /></label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Без скрипта (плюс сто к производительности) и с лейблами, приведенными в правильный вид:

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid navy;
  position: relative;
}

.locker {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  backdrop-filter: blur(1px);
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  display: none;
}

[name="radio"],
[name="radio"]+label {
  position: relative;
}

[name="radio"]:checked,
[name="radio"]:checked+label {
  z-index: 2;
}

[name="radio"]:checked~.locker {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio" /><label for="radio1">КНОПКА 1</label><br/>
  <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio" /><label for="radio2">КНОПКА 2</label><br/>
  <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radio" /><label for="radio3">КНОПКА 3</label><br/>
  <div class="locker"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Имеет право на жизнь. Но, как с расширяемостью? Что, если будет несколько групп с разным количеством кнопок?

Comment: @UModeL, каждая группа просто суется в свой контейнер.  главное тут чтобы `.locker` был последним и доступен для css после чекбоксов (для этого и вывел их из лейблов, тем более, что так правильнее). количество радиокнопок может быть любым, равно и как их расположение, а также наличие любых других элементов.

Comment: любым то любым, но... другая группа - другой `name`, а значит, ещё  CSS добавится. То же самое и с количеством кнопок - каждой добавляется уникальный `id`, хотя при заявленных условиях, проще получать выбор по индексу.

Comment: на `name` я завязался исключительно от лени писать input[type="radio"]. так что можно использовать везде. а уникальный id у радиокнопок-инпутов и должен быть, если по-хорошему